# How to unset OnitemClickListener in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my case, I have a recyclerview which it's fill with data, so I set a OnItemClickListener.
But with sorting options, this recyclerview can be empty. The fact is that I still can click on item. I already try to re set the OnitemClickListener with nothing in the OnItemClick(), but it do not solve my problem.

```
public RecyclerView rendreNonCliquable(RecyclerView p_recyclerView){
        p_recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerClickListener(getActivity(), p_recyclerView, new RecyclerClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
        return  p_recyclerView;
    }
```

Thank's for help.

Comment: show the code where you set the OnItemClickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs for [onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener#onrequestdisallowintercepttouchevent), so I guess something like :

```
p_recyclerView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
```

should do the trick.